# Elasticsearch query using NEST & QueryRaw

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I have the following Elastic Search query:

```
 {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "main",
                    "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields": [
                        "field1^5",
                        "test",
                        "field2",
                        "abc"
                    ],
                    "operator": "and"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [],
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20
}
```

I am trying to run this query using NEST client for Elastic Search & using "**QueryRaw**" attribute but getting Error.

Can someone please provide some input where I am going wrong

```
var uri = new Uri("Elastic_Search_Cluster_Name");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri, defaultIndex: "testIndex");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var resp=client.Search<dynamic>(q => 
q.Type("mappingType").QueryRaw(inputRequest.ToString())
);
```

Error Log:

```
Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[27THF3S_QuaBLRj11MgqfA][testIndex][0]: RemoteTransportException[[pdm64-ironman][inet[/server]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[testIndex][0]: query[abc:main field2:main test:main field1:main^5.0],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "main",
        "type": "cross_fields",
        "fields": [
          "field1^5",
          "test",
          "field2",
          "abc"
        ],
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_ARRAY "sort"]; }{[b5YxyDCcQEmSlCd9y3Sfww][testIndex][1]: RemoteTransportException[[pdm65-hulk][inet[/server]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[testIndex][1]: query[abc:main field2:main test:main field1:main^5.0],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{
  "query": {
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "multi_match": {
        "query": "main",
        "type": "cross_fields",
        "fields": [
          "field1^5",
          "test",
          "field2",
          "abc"
        ],
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
}]]];
```

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting? The raw query looks fine.

Comment: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[xcv23jfTQtmaFhb1PQ62pQ][rpdw][0]: SearchParseException[testIndex][0]:

Comment: May you post how request to ES looks like`Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resp.RequestInformation.Request);`?

Comment: Can you mention the value of `inputRequest`?

Comment: inputRequest is of Type "JToken". I am just sending the above json to the method. If I send this simple JSON its working: {"match_all":{}}

Comment: Include more detail of the error. It will have additional details for shard failure. I have tried your raw query and it works just fine.

Comment: Updated Error Log Above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire search request cannot be passed into `QueryRaw`. You can only pass the JSON request that is supposed to be included inside a `"query"` object into `QueryRaw`. Hence if you pass the below JSON body into `QueryRaw` it should work.

```
{
   "filtered": {
      "query": {
         "multi_match": {
            "query": "main",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
               "field1^5",
               "test",
               "field2",
               "abc"
            ],
            "operator": "and"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But `"sort"`, `"from"` and `"size"` objects are not inside `"query"` and hence Nest fails to parse your request.

What your Nest code should look like is as below:

```
var uri = new Uri("Elastic_Search_Cluster_Name");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri, defaultIndex: "testIndex");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var resp = client.Search<dynamic>(q => q
    .Type("mappingType")
    .QueryRaw(<raw query string>)
    .From(0)
    .Size(20)
);
```

I left out `Sort()` in the above Nest search request because you were not doing anything with it anyways.

Comment: "You can only pass the JSON request that is supposed to be included inside a "query" object into QueryRaw" - is there a way to prevent this behavior and pass the whole query string through?

Comment: @daviddeath For that you'll need to use the Raw client of Nest. Mind you, in that case, the response you'll receive will also be in raw format.